# Response redirect to same page with querystring on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response

I have a page called: `Welcome.aspx`

In the page load of that page I did: `Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx?First=true")`

So when I visit `Welcome.aspx` the site keeps redirecting and it doesn't stop (logical).

What can I do to stop the redirecting? I just want that the redirect happens just once. So when someone visits `Welcome.aspx` they must be redirected to `Welcome.aspx?First=true` just once. And after that the response.redirect must stop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only do the redirect if QueryString["First"] is not equal to "true" (though I think your naming and logic don't really match there). Something like:

```
void Page_Load( ... )
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (QueryString["VisitFlag"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx?VisitFlag=Done");
    }
}
```